# Resolve conflicts with clang-tidy modernize-use-using

Tags: c++11, clang-format, clang-static-analyzer

I am using the modernize-use-using checker from clang-tidy through the run-clang-tidy-3.9.py script over a whole CMake project (I use the compile_commands.json file generated by cmake).

This works great for other modernize checkers (auto, for loops, override, etc.), but the modernize-use-using checker finds "conflicts" like for instance:

```
    There are conflicting changes to /home/OTB/git/otb/Modules/Filtering/ImageManipulation/include/otbVectorRescaleIntensityImageFilter.h:

The following changes conflict:

Replace 48:3-48:84 with "using RealType = typename itk::NumericTraits<typename TInput::ValueType>::RealType"

Replace 48:3-48:84 with "using RealType = typename itk::NumericTraits<typename VariableLengthVector<double>::ValueType>::RealType"

Replace 48:3-48:84 with "using RealType = typename itk::NumericTraits<typename VariableLengthVector<float>::ValueType>::RealType"
```

Looking at the source code, I don't understand why there would be such conflicts, but the issue is that because of these, no other fix is applied to my project. These are very few conflicts relative to the number of fixes, but I can't find a way to force clang-tidy to apply the rest.

The clang-tidy tool, when run alone has a -fix-errors option, but this is not available for the run-clang-tidy script which uses the CMake commands file.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `run-clang-tidy.py` as of LLVM 5.0 seems to use `-fix` as its command line flag to apply fixes. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Or is it that you need the full `-fix-errors` capability? If the latter, maybe add it in to the `run-clang-tidy.py` file right after the line where it adds the `-fix` parameter so that `fix-errors` is also available as a parameter. I haven't tried it though but that seems like it should work.